# Expected loss function in matlab

Tags: matlab, expected-value, loss-functions

I have two matrices: The true one and the approximated one.

In fact I want to compute the expected loss of the difference, that is, $E[||\Sigma_{approximated} - \Sigma_{true}||]$.

In matlab, I computed first the L2 norm of $\Sigma_{approximated} - \Sigma_{true}$:

```
Loss = norm(sigma_approx - sigma_true, 2);
```

but how an I compute the expectation of this Loss?

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: An expected loss (or any expected value for that matter) is a parameter associated with the distribution of a random variable. Here you appear to have a single realisation without any distributional assumptions for $\Sigma_{approx.}$ or $\Sigma_{true}$ so not many things can be said... BTW you might want to consider Frobenius if you comparing the difference of two matrices. (Frobenius and $L_2$ are equivalent for vectors but not matrices)

Comment: In fact yes I have a normal distribution, these $\Sigma$s are for vectors which come from normal distribution. So what can be the value of the expectation?

Comment: The difference of Gaussians is still Gaussian.

Comment: Okay but does the expectation here depends on the pdf Under normality ?

Comment: Apologies, I cannot understand what you mean by this side-question.

Comment: Are you trying to say that sigma_approx is an estimated covariance based on n samples of a p dimensional normal? If so, then of course this depends on your method of estimation.  I recall you have had a number of posts pertaining to different covariance estimators, designed for instance to improve the conditioning of the estimated covariance. And as usεr11852 pointed out, choice of norm is important. 2-norm will give you largest singular value of the difference of the matrices - is  that really what you want?  Only you know.

Comment: Hallo yes in fact it is and I tried the L2-norm instead of the Frobenius. Thank you for your answer! :)